# how to reset wamp server password

Tags: wampserver

I've put the password in the main phpmyadmin and not one of the databases.
How can I even access it if can't even have the chance to input the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at reseting the MySQL root password [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows).

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a blank password but don't do it.

Comment: It's working. I created Password for phpmyadmin  WAMPservser2.4 in FF. To revert that password to root user to empty this commnad working for me.

Answer (score 1):

First check if you assigned empty password. There is a high probability not to assign password when you install locally.

Answer (score 0):

solution is on this page
[wamp server mysql user id and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420894/wamp-server-mysql-user-id-and-password/41958504#41958504)