# wamp server mysql user id and password

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have wamp installed , I want to know how to create username and password in mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change password for MySQL Console in WAMP 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971703/how-to-change-password-for-mysql-console-in-wamp-2-5)

Answer (score 43):

By default, you can access your databases at http:// localhost/phpmyadmin using user: *root* and a blank password.

Once logged in PHPmyAdmin, click on the *Privileges tab*. and on the *Add a new user* link located under the *User Overview* table

Answer (score 32):

Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin and click on the Privileges tab. There is a "Add a new user" link.
[image]

Comment: I don't have a privileges tab

Comment: @curtis You have to click on the database on the left hand side then the privileges tab will show

Comment: This option won't work if you opted to not install phpmyadmin.

Comment: In a default installation, you have to login as user root, and password as blank before you can do this.

Comment: @Curtis There is User Accounts Tab

Answer (score 18):

[image]

Hit enter as there is no password. Enter the following commands:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'localhost' = password('enteryourpassword');
mysql> SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = password('enteryourpassword');
mysql> SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'::1' = password('enteryourpassword');
```

That’s it, I keep the passwords the same to keep things simple. If you want to check the user’s table to see that the info has been updated just enter the additional commands as shown below. This is a good option to check that you have indeed entered the same password for all hosts.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41958436/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: Thanks. I tried other answers but none of them worked, except yours.

Answer (score 10):

Simply goto MySql Console.

If using Wamp:

1. Click on Wamp icon just beside o'clock.
2. In MySql section click on MySql Console.
3. Press enter (means no password) twice.
4. mysql commands preview like this : mysql>
5. SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('secret');

That's it.
This set your root password to secret

In order to set user privilege to default one:

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Previous answers might not work for later mysql versions. Try these steps if previous answers did not work for you:

1. Click on the wamp icon &rarr: mysql → mysql console
2. write following commands, one by one

   ```
   use mysql;
   update user set authentication_string=password('your_password') where user='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   quit
   ```

Comment: had to add "mysql"  here:   update mysql.user .... but works like charm

Answer (score 4):

You can create a user using `MySQL` like this:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'servername' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and if you want to do that for a specific database, simply you can write in the `MySQL`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.*
TO 'username'@'servername'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Note that it's all one sentence, also note that you need to change:

```
database_name // your database name
username      // any name you want to use as username
servername    // the name of your server, for example: localhost
password      // any text you want to use as user password
```

Comment: Where do I type this? I typed it into the command prompt in mysql.exe and nothing happened, it just gives me a new line with -> and a blinking cursor no matter what I type

Answer (score 4):

Just login into http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

with username:root

password:

with blank password.
And then choose users account.And then choose add user account.

Answer (score 3):

**WAMP Server – MySQL – Resetting the Root Password (Windows)**

1. Log on to your system as Administrator.
2. Click on the Wamp server icon > MySQL > MySQL Console
3. Enter password: LEAVE BLANK AND HIT ENTER
4. mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(‘MyNewPass’) WHERE User=’root’; ENTER
   Query OK
5. mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ENTER
   mysql>quit ENTER
   mysql>bye
6. Edit phpmyadmin file called “config.inc.php” enter ‘MyNewPass’ ($cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ‘MyNewPass‘;)
7. Restart all services
8. Clear all cookies – I got the No password error and it was because of the cookies. (ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: ‘root@localhost’ (Using password: NO))

Answer (score 2):

Changing or Adding UserName and Password for Wamp server

1. Go to [phpmyadmn](http://localhost/phpmyadmin). Default username is **root** and password is empty (blank)
2. Go to **[User accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSKfg.png)** tab.

If you cannot see the tab,then go to Home page of phpmyadmin without selecting any DB.

3. Here  click on [Add user account](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/server_privileges.php?adduser=1) to add New Account
4. If you want to change password for existing users, then click on [Edit privileges](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/server_privileges.php?username=root&hostname=localhost&dbname=&tablename=&routinename=) and select **[Chanage password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tHMm.png)** Tab

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the MySQL documentation on creating new user accounts.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

In short, you create a user by running a [`CREATE USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) statement:

```
CREATE USER "<username>" IDENTIFIED BY "<password>";
```

Once the user is created, you give him access to do things by using the [`GRANT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `http://localhost/sqlbuddy --> users` interface.

You can find it at the localhost main page at `Your Aliases` section.

Answer (score 1):

Go to phpmyadmin and click on the database you have already created form the left side bar. Then you can see a privilege option at the top.. There you can add a new user..

If you are not having any database yet go to phpmyadmin and select databases and create a database by simply giving database name in the filed and press go.

Answer (score 1):

Darkcoder's solution is the only one that made it work for me. (WAMP server 2.5, which includes mysql 5.6.17. + client is Workbench 6.3)

In order for any additional user (other than the default root) to be able to see the schemas in Workbench, I had to create 3 times each additional user.

```
Once for host = %
Once for host = localhost
Once for host = ::1
```

Also, I noticed that in order for the granted privileges to really work (global and per database ones), I had to make sure all privileges were exactly the same for all the 3 different user+host combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to log in with the username "admin" and it let me got in, but without any privileges and I did not know that. Then I tried with the username "root", and then I had privileges so I changed the privileges to the other users. Both usernames do not use passwords, so I leave them blank.