# How to change root password of phpmyadmin in WAMP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I opened mysql console and wrote the following :

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('temppass')  ;
```

Now when I open phpmyadmin,  it says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I was trying to set a password for root and I read it somewhere that we change root password from console itself,  unlike previous versions where we had to alter the config files.

Any detailed tutorial on changing root password to secure a database?

I'm new to all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have changed the `root` password you need to tell phpMyAdmin what the new password is as by default the `root` password is held in the `c:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\phpmyadmin.conf` file.

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD';        <--change
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;              <--change
```

A better solution in my opinion is to change this file so that phpMyAdmin throws a login screen so you can enter/test new accounts as well as just `root`

So I would change `c:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\phpmyadmin.conf` to

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Now you will get a login screen like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the default `mysql` **root** password on `xampp`, type the following on **mysql** console:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('som3P@Ss') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then open `[XAMPP Installation Path] /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
and modify it to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'som3P@Ss';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```