# reset/change mysql root password

Tags: mysql, wamp, bitnami

**How to reset/change mysql root password in [bitnami wamp stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp)?**

I trying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211725/how-to-reset-wamp-server-password) but this not working for me. In the bitnami folder no have file *\bin\mysqld-nt.exe*

Comment: mysqld-nt is the same as mysqld, just that it brings support for named pipes on windows-nt machines. Do you have a mysqld.exe? And does the linked solution for you, if you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolve the problem:

1.
stop service wampstackMySQL (From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services)

1.
in windows cmd code:

> E:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.34-0\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=E:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.34-0/mysql\my.ini wampstackMySQL --init-file=E:\mysql-init.txt

**mysql-init.txt code:**

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

2.
connect to mysql server via [workbench](http://:%20From%20the%20Start%20menu,%20select%20Control%20Panel,%20then%20Administrative%20Tools,%20then%20Services) with new root password

3.
restart PC or restart service wampstackMySQL

4.
delete file mysql-init.txt

Comment: mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: /.../my.ini

Answer (score 0):

```
ankichan@ankichan-HP-Notebook:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Then do the following steps:
    Execute bash as root
    sudo bash
    Enter the regular password of your user
    Change root password using:
    passwd root
```

This will allow you to set a root password
eg.

```
ankichan@ankichan-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for ankichan: 
root@ankichan-HP-Notebook:~# passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

---

```
root@ankichan-HP-Notebook:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
```